# Java Digital Signature does not match C# (SHA1withRSA)

Tags: java, c#, base64, x509certificate, keystore

So I am not the Crypto wizard by any means but here is some code I have that works in C# but does not return the same b64 string in Java.
c#

---

```
 string _Cert = "long b64 string here";  
 string _Pass = "my password";  
 string lvreturn = "Test";  
 byte[] lvCertBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(_Cert);  
 X509Certificate2 lvCertFromBytes = new X509Certificate2(lvCertBytes, _Pass);  
 SHA1Managed lvSHA1 = new SHA1Managed();  
 byte[] lvData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(lvReturn);  
 byte[] lvHash = lvSHA1.ComputeHash(lvData);

RSACryptoServiceProvider lvCryptoProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)lvCertFromBytes.PrivateKey;
byte[] lvSignedBytes = lvCryptoProvider.SignHash(lvHash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));  
string lvToken = Convert.ToBase64String(lvSignedBytes);
```

Java

---

```
String certB64 = "long b64 string here";
char[] Pass = "text password".toCharArray();
String alias = "guid looking ID here";      
String plaintext = "Test";


byte[] certbytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certB64);

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(certbytes);

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keystore.load(in,Pass); 


KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pvk = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keystore.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(Pass));
PrivateKey pkey = (PrivateKey)pvk.getPrivateKey();

Signature rsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
rsa.initSign(pkey);
rsa.update(plaintext.getBytes());
System.out.println("Hash: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rsa.sign()));
```

I have Cert.pfx file that I want to use to use the privatekey to encrypt a https auth segment.  I am just ripping the file to a base64 string and stuffing it into the "_Cert" var in C#.  I do the same in Java.  I want to sign the plaintext message using the private key of the cert and SHA1.  The C# code below works and the https server provides a response.  Java however is not spitting out the same base64 encoded string.  Thanks for some help!

**Update:** I found a link to another post that is the same as mine but with a couple small diffs, and I didn't want to necro post on it.  I followed it exactly removing the messagedigest piece of my original code.  I tried reading directly from the pfx file or using the b64 string directly in the code.  I am still not getting the same between Java and C#.  At this point it has to be something small I am missing with encoding in Java because the C# is basically identical to mine.

[Java Digital Signature different to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338034/java-digital-signature-different-to-c-sharp)

Comment: Finally figured it out.  I don't know why but apparently Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes in C# equals plaintext.getBytes("UTF-16LE") in Java.  Maybe someone that understands encoding and "endianness" could explain.  I thought Java was natively unicode, and endianness only mattered if you went between processor types.